# SQLITE (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: python, database, windows, sqlite, command-prompt

*I am a beginner, currently learning Python. This is my first time asking a doubt on this platform.
 I (I have inserted the image here->[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2sMJ.jpg) )downloaded the sqlite database from sqlite.org for my windows laptop and now when i run the command prompt and try to access sqlite from there, it is saying path not found.
I am extremely confused as this is my firs time with any computer language... I am unable to figure out what the problem is. I have also typed out the problem below.*

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.914]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\myusername>cd\

C:>cd sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3320100

**The system cannot find the path specified.**

C:>

Comment: Have you confirmed that sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3320100 is a directory/folder on your C: drive? If you haven’t, either check using file explorer, or execute the “dir” command in CMD to confirm it’s listed. If using CMD, ensure that if it’s listed in the output of “dir” that it has “<dir>” in front of the name.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Looks like your directory is not where you believe it is or has a differing name. If you are prepared to install a helper tool, I'd recommend this: https://everything.en.softonic.com/?ex=MOB-392.1
Everything will map your entire harddrive and offer a search textbox that will instantly (!) find any file on your computer even if you only can provide a partial file name like, e.g., "sqlite-tools-win32" as might be useful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

After you downloaded the zip(?) file, did you extract it? If so, *where* did you extract it to? Assuming you downloaded it to the default location `Downloads`, and extracted the zip file there: your user directory is the default folder when you do `cmd`. Your Downloads are under that, so from the starting point, do `cd Downloads` (press Tab key after typing `Dow` to make use of auto-completion). Then `cd sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3320100` (again, use Tab-completion instead of typing the whole thing) since that folder is where the extracted zip contents would go, by default.

So:

```
C:\Users\your_username>cd Downloads

C:\Users\your_username\Downloads>cd sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3320100

C:\Users\your_username\Downloads\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3320100>dir
```

FYI, you can do both `cd`'s in one command:

```
C:\Users\your_username>cd Downloads\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3320100

C:\Users\your_username\Downloads\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3320100>
```